# Change properties of any control within a parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Does anyone know how to call any object (label, textbox, panel) from a parent form. for example, i have a Form A and this form has a Label L, Textbox T and Button B. Is any way i pass the entire form through a function (public DoSomething(Form f)) and then change the properties of Label L, Textbox T and Button B in function DoSomething?

```
class DoSomething{
 private Form parentForm;
 public DoSomething(Form f) {
   parentForm = f;
   // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO CHANGE PROPERTIES OF LABEL L, BUTTON B
 }
}
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all form controls and change the properties for each control:

```
foreach (Control c in parentForm.Controls)
{
   if (c is Label && c.Name == "L")
   {
       // Do label stuff here
   }
   else if (c is TextBox && c.Name == "T")
   {
       // Do text box stuff here
   }
   if (c is Button && c.Name == "B")
   {
       // Do button stuff here
   }
}
```

If you want to find the controls by their names, you can try this:

```
Label L = (Label)parentForm.Controls.Find("L");
TextBox T = (TextBox)parentForm.Controls.Find("T");
Button B = (Button)parentForm.Controls.Find("B");

// Do stuff with L, T and B here...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that the class Form doesn't conating the properties of your interest.

Indise DoSomething you have to convert the form to the original type to access its controls:

```
 if (f is Form1)
 {
    Form1 f1 = f as Form1;
    f1.C... // here all the properties of the class form1 Are available.
 }
```

If all the forms have common properties, you can create an interface, and implement it in all your forms. And set the parameter type of your `DoSomething` to the type of the interface:

```
void DoSomething(IFomrInterface fi)
{
  fi.C... // this will have all the propertie savailabel in the interface
}
```

The second solution is more generic. All the forms should implement the interface:

```
class Form1: Form, IFormInterface
```

Answer (score 0):

Try set controls of the parents form properties to `Modifier to Public`.

In child form,use as

```
parentForm.btnA.Name="ButtonB";
```

Hope it works!